# Alias a npm module with browserify shim

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm moving from requirejs to browserify.

I have a dependency for masonry.

That was proving a little difficult ([more on that here](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/670)), to shim using the bower version.

So I just installed it with `npm` which installs it as `masonry-layout`.

My question is: How can I shim the named import of a `npm` modules with [`thlorenz/browserify-shim`](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim)? So I don't have to change every reference in my code from `masonry` to `masonry-layout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's the right use case for browserify-shim. Here are a few ideas:

- You might be able to accomplish what you want using the `browser` field in `package.json`. E.g.:

  ```
  "browser": {
    "masonry": "masonry-layout"
  }
  ```
- If you don't care about being able to install the masonry package as a dependency of the same project and you have symlinks you could symlink `node_modules/masonry` to `node_modules/masonry-layout`.
- You could try my [pathmodify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathmodify) browserify plugin.